# How to catch exceptions caused by a malformed layout-xml file?

Tags: android, exception, android-widget, android-layout, android-xml

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //R.layout.main has an illegal element (e.g. no layout_height attribute) 
            //But no exception is thrown at this line.
            setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        } //Exception will be thrown after this line. Where to catch it?
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you serious? That kind of things cannot be just "*catched*"... they have to be fixed. Just fix your XML file and that's it... it does not make sense to catch such as Exception; what would you do after catching it?

Comment: +1 to Cristian. @OneWorld: If your Layout XML is malformed then your application is broken.

Comment: @Christian: Of course this things must be fixed. However, it also must be possible to catch those things. @Octavian: If the XML of an activity is malformed then this Activity is broken, not the application. So, I can finish it, show appropriate Toasts and Log the error.

Comment: @OneWorld: Why should the layout of an activity you built be malformed? This makes no sense. Why would you publish an application with a broken activity?

Comment: @OneWorld trust me, while developing with Android you will find that not all Exceptions can be caught. Just fix your layout, case closed.